# Xamarin MvvmCross projects - Project Not Built in Active Configuration

Tags: ios, xamarin, build, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I have an iOS Solution which has an iPhone project and two other PCL libraries that contain my MvvmCross ViewModels and Model. I am using Xamarin Studio for Mac.

When I select to build the solution for the iOS simulator everything is fine. When I change it to build for the iPhone, The other MvvmCross projects indicate that they are not built in the active configuration.

Should this happen? I'm unsure. For these projects I can only select AnyCPU there is no option to select iPhone

The project builds and it deploys and runs on the iPhone, but crashes with no exception.